# Django calendar widget in a custom form

Tags: django, django-forms

I am trying to add a calendar date input to one of my forms. There is a wonderful calendar widget that Django uses on its admin pages, but I can't figure out how to add it to a custom form.

I found a couple other questions about the same subject here, but they all seemed to be out of date, complicated, and not working.

Is there a way to include Django's built in calendar widget into one of my forms?

Comment: The simplest and quickest way I found so far is using [forms.widgets.DateInput](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38804177/888367)

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32544473/5802289) below, it is the most updated one and it is totally straightforward. However, note that this provides 3 drop-down menus (year, month, day) instead of just a calendar box...which IMO is a bit annoying.

Comment: I manage to get it working on Django 2.0.2. Refer to my Answer on this link. [Django 2 AdminDateWidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12449603/integrate-calendar-widget-in-django-app/49083226#49083226)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I figured it out, thanks to Dave S. and a number of old posts on this topic. My successful method:

### Create a custom form.

At the top, import the admin widgets using `from django.contrib.admin.widgets import AdminDateWidget`. Then, add the different fields of your form, using `my_field = DateField(widget = AdminDateWidget)` whenever you want to use the date widget.

### Create your form template

Place the following toward the top to include the appropriate css/js files:

```
{% load i18n admin_modify adminmedia %}
{% block extrahead %}{{ block.super }}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% admin_media_prefix %}css/base.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% admin_media_prefix %}css/widgets.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jsi18n/"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% admin_media_prefix %}js/core.js"></script>
{{ form.media }}
{% endblock %}
```

*Note: You do not necessarily need all of this, depending upon your version of Django and how you are implementing the form fields. this is what I found that I needed to use the widgets.*

Now just output your form like normal, and the JS should automatically convert it to a date field. Enjoy!

Comment: If jsi18n lives somewhere else, here is the way to go: {% url 'admin:jsi18n' as jsi18nurl %} <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ jsi18nurl }}"></script> (For older Django versions you might also want {% load url from future %})

Comment: For this to fully work as in the admin you should also add these js files to your header alongside the core.js <script type="text/javascript" src="{% admin_media_prefix %}js/calendar.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="{% admin_media_prefix %}js/admin/DateTimeShortcuts.js"></script>

Answer (score 28):

Instead of the Admin widget, consider using the normal "SelectDateWidget" built into Django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/forms/widgets/#selectdatewidget

Comment: This is the better modern way to do this. The other answers are too old now.

Comment: Perfect! Then the only thing needed is writing in the Form class definition: `Date = forms.DateField(widget = forms.SelectDateWidget)`

Comment: add-on that is useful, to select the range of years that people can chose from (example from 2017 to 2020): widget = SelectDateWidget(years=range(2017, 2020))

Comment: Pro - incredibly easy. Cons - incredibly ugly. Doesn't convey the day of the month at all. Why on earth does Django ship with a viable calendar widget that is so incredibly difficult to integrate into your app?

Answer (score 12):

All widgets used by django-admin are in the django/contrib/admin/widgets.py file. Just use that as a usual widget in a form. What you want is AdminDateWidget.

```
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import AdminDateWidget
from django.forms.fields import DateField

class MyForm(Form):
    my_field = DateField(widget=AdminDateWidget)
```

That will create a date-picker with calendar. You may try to customize it to what you need by extending it or create a new widget from a scratch with an inspiration from AdminDateWidget.

Comment: when I try the code above, I get an error that `DateField` is not defined. I also tried `forms.DateField`, but then I just end up with a txt field.

Comment: It seems that my template isn't outputting the required JS files at the top. Is there another tag needed for my template to include those?

Comment: You should import DateField `from django.forms.fields import DateField` I am sure you figured it out.

And yeah there's a tag which you have to use in template `{% load i18n %}` for javascript to load. I used base.html template from admin, so I didn't have to import all needed files.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this by form widget " SelectDateWidget()" like this example:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):

        start_date=forms.DateField(widget = forms.SelectDateWidget())
        end_date=forms.DateField(widget = forms.SelectDateWidget())
```

Comment: This is the easiest and neatest way other than installing a third party app

Answer (score 1):

use django form widget called NumberInput as the widget for any datefield or datetimefield in Django This will render the basic HTML NumberInput field for the user to select. I just tested this and it works when the backend recieves the date if you treat it like a python `datetime` object

```
from django.forms.widgets import NumberInput

# label and required are both optional arguments  
date_input = forms.DateTimeField(label="Date", required=True, widget=NumberInput(attrs={'type':'date'}))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is basically a duplicate of [Using Django time/date widgets in custom form](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38601/445210).

The answer has been given by @Dave S and @MrGlass, but for Django 1.2 and later this will additionally also be needed to help the JavaScript find the admin media:

```
{% load adminmedia %} /* At the top of the template. */

/* In the head section of the template. */
<script type="text/javascript">
window.__admin_media_prefix__ = "{% filter escapejs %}{% admin_media_prefix %}{% endfilter %}";
</script>
```

(from [Carl Meyer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38601/using-django-time-date-widgets-in-custom-form/38916#38916))

Answer (score 0):

If anyone would be still looking for a neat solution then here's what I found in the internet:

write in file 'forms.py':

```
from django.forms import DateInput

class DateInput(DateInput):
    input_type = 'date'

class DateForm(Form):
    date = DateField(widget=DateInput)
```

then simply use the form in your 'views.py':

```
date = DateForm()
```

You will get such view:
[date widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3tgo.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily by using the DateField widget.

example:

birth_date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'type':'date'}))