# Integrate calendar widget in Django app

Tags: django, calendar, datepicker

How do I integrate a calendar widget in my system? I wish to add the calendar widget to my form, which has been designed in Django. I'm attaching a screenshot showing where I want to integrate it. Also, I want the calendar widget to be like http://www.dynarch.com/projects/calendar/.

What file do I need to modify and what code do I need to use?

[image]

Comment: check the link it may solve your issue                   


**http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38601/using-django-time-date-widgets-in-custom-form**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

forms.py

```
import datetime
from django.forms.extras.widgets import SelectDateWidget
from django.forms import ModelForm, Form

date_field = forms.DateField(widget=SelectDateWidget)
```

or else there is also a another way using Javascript [Using Django time/date widgets in custom form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38601/using-django-time-date-widgets-in-custom-form)
it may be helpful

Comment: it always says 'DateField' object has no attribute 'needs_multipart_form'..what can i do to correct it?

Comment: `SelectDateWidget` is ideal. Why do none of the other umpteen threads about the same question mention it??

Answer (score 9):

I figured it out. You just need to activate the admin interface in settings.py and  import AdminDateWidget instead of SelectDateWidget in the forms.py file. Also, insert the following code into the template file of the form. Make sure to put it in between  tags. here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/admin/jsi18n/"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/admin/RelatedObjectLookups.js">        </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/jquery.init.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/actions.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/calendar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/admin/DateTimeShortcuts.js"></script>
```

Hope its of use to somebody, cheers!

Saadat

Answer (score 5):

After a long struggle, I managed to get it working for Django 2.0.2. You need the following in the header of template:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jsi18n/"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'admin/js/core.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'admin/js/admin/RelatedObjectLookups.js' %}"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'admin/css/forms.css' %}"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'admin/css/base.css' %}"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'admin/css/widgets.css' %}"/>
```

urls.py

```
from django.views.i18n import JavaScriptCatalog


urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('jsi18n/', JavaScriptCatalog.as_view(), name='javascript-catalog'),

]
```

And then forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import MyModel
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import AdminDateWidget


class TripDetailForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'my_field': AdminDateWidget(),
}
```

With this code, you must be good to go.

Comment: This did not work for me but I'm not getting any errors.  The form is widget for my date field is still a text box.  I'm rendering with  {{ form.as_p }}

Comment: I was able to get it to work by adding two more lines `<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'admin/js/calendar.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'admin/js/admin/DateTimeShortcuts.js' %}"></script>
`

Comment: @MarkChackerian those lines can be replace with this tag {{form.media}}, which is much more shorter

Comment: Just a heads up you don't need this lines. This will just mess up your forms.                                                      
 `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'admin/css/forms.css' %}"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'admin/css/base.css' %}"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Just a tip for people who are using **Django_filters** and they want the admin calendar to show on there date fields (E.x Date is greater than) .. You need to declare the widget in the filter you created .

Like this :

```
class InterviewFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    start_date = django_filters.DateFilter(name='date',lookup_expr=('gt'), widget=AdminDateWidget())
    end_date = django_filters.DateFilter(name='date',lookup_expr=('lt'), widget=AdminDateWidget()) 
    registry_year = django_filters.DateRangeFilter(field_name='date', lookup_expr='year')

    class Meta:
        model = Interview
        fields = ['position', 'result', 'status']
```