# Using date picker from django admin

Tags: django, datetime, django-admin

I'm new to Django and I'm trying to find the Django Admin date picker widget. I have search but got no results. Could anyone help me to use it on the project I'm working on?

I have a datetimefield in my model, like this:

```
fin = models.DateTimeField()
```

When creating a model from the admin is shows the widget but when I do it from the project it doesn't.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Specify the widget in your form as follows:

```
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import AdminDateWidget

class YourForm(forms.ModelForm):
        from_date = forms.DateField(widget=AdminDateWidget())
```

Don't forget to include the scripts and css in your template:

```
{{ form.media }}
```

Comment: Hi Alex. Thank you for the reply. I'm still having problems to show the calendar and the "Now" feature. Is that external to the AdminDateWidget()? Is there a way I can see documentation about this?

Comment: The common pitfall is to forget to include forms' media (css and js files) in the template. Have you done it? Like, `{{ form.media }}`.

Comment: @AlexMorozov Using only `{{ form.media }}` does not work. Other admin related css and js files have to be included as mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/a/12916263/3590449

Answer (score 9):

If for some reason you are looking to use the date picker with a PostgreSQL `DateRangeField`, you can do so like so:

```
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import AdminDateWidget
from django.contrib.postgres.forms.ranges import DateRangeField, 
RangeWidget

class YourForm(forms.ModelForm):
    date_range = DateRangeField(widget=RangeWidget(AdminDateWidget()))
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me inside Django-admin

```
class CustomAdminDateWidget(forms.DateInput):
    class Media:
        js = ("/admin/jsi18n/", 
              "/static/admin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.js", 
              "/static/admin/js/calendar.js", 
              "/static/admin/js/jquery.init.js", 
              "/static/admin/js/admin/DateTimeShortcuts.js", 
              "/static/admin/js/core.js")

    def __init__(self, attrs=None, format=None):
        attrs = {'class': 'vDateField', 'size': '10', **(attrs or {})}
        super().__init__(attrs=attrs, format=format)

class DateRangeForm(forms.Form):
    start_date = forms.DateField(label='From Date', widget=CustomAdminDateWidget)
    end_date = forms.DateField(label='To Date', widget=CustomAdminDateWidget)
```

## In the template head section

```
{{ form.media }}
```