# How to implement a calendar in Django

Tags: django, calendar

This may or may not be a large topic but I'm trying to implement a calendar in my Django app. I have `event` models that have a `event_time` field. On the front-end, I've built an html calendar ui, but I'm wondering how to implement the months. Should months be models and does that just mean I have to manually add all the months myself? Or is there an existing back-end for this?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking, a calendar is essentially a ui element. it shouldnt have anything to do with your models

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12449603/integrate-calendar-widget-in-django-app

Comment: Could you please describe a task you trying to solve a little bit widely? From what you said models for months looks like an overhead. Are you trying to make UI for user to fill dates in some inputs?