# both jQuery and $ is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I already imported

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

under the head section. But still I got,

```
RelatedObjectLookups.js:142 Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
    at RelatedObjectLookups.js:142
    at RelatedObjectLookups.js:175
(anonymous) @ RelatedObjectLookups.js:142
(anonymous) @ RelatedObjectLookups.js:175
(index):177 Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
    at (index):177
```

Relavant html looks like,

```
<head>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <script crossorigin="anonymous" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin="anonymous" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link crossorigin="anonymous" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" rel="stylesheet"> 
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/admin/jsi18n/"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/admin/RelatedObjectLookups.js">        </script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/jquery.init.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/actions.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/calendar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/admin/DateTimeShortcuts.js"></script> 
{{form.media}}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
        <form method="post" id="extendTrialForm" class="form">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {% bootstrap_field form.user %}
            {% bootstrap_field form.core_instance %}
            {% bootstrap_field form.expiry_datetime %}
            {% buttons %}
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            {% endbuttons %}
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<script>

$( document ).ready(function() { // line no 177
```

Removing the script tags above `{{form.media}}` won't throw any error related to jquery but it misses the widget functionality. I need that script tags but I don't want Jquery to return `$` is not a function. I have tried adding `$.noconflict`, `jQuery(document).ready` but nothing works.

`RelatedObjectsLookups.js`

```
/*global SelectBox, interpolate*/
// Handles related-objects functionality: lookup link for raw_id_fields
// and Add Another links.

(function($) {
    'use strict';

    // IE doesn't accept periods or dashes in the window name, but the element IDs
    // we use to generate popup window names may contain them, therefore we map them
    // to allowed characters in a reversible way so that we can locate the correct
    // element when the popup window is dismissed.
    function id_to_windowname(text) {
        text = text.replace(/\./g, '__dot__');
        text = text.replace(/\-/g, '__dash__');
        return text;
    }

    function windowname_to_id(text) {
        text = text.replace(/__dot__/g, '.');
        text = text.replace(/__dash__/g, '-');
        return text;
    }

    function showAdminPopup(triggeringLink, name_regexp, add_popup) {
        var name = triggeringLink.id.replace(name_regexp, '');
        name = id_to_windowname(name);
        var href = triggeringLink.href;
        if (add_popup) {
            if (href.indexOf('?') === -1) {
                href += '?_popup=1';
            } else {
                href += '&_popup=1';
            }
        }
        var win = window.open(href, name, 'height=500,width=800,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes');
        win.focus();
        return false;
    }

    function showRelatedObjectLookupPopup(triggeringLink) {
        return showAdminPopup(triggeringLink, /^lookup_/, true);
    }

    function dismissRelatedLookupPopup(win, chosenId) {
        var name = windowname_to_id(win.name);
        var elem = document.getElementById(name);
        if (elem.className.indexOf('vManyToManyRawIdAdminField') !== -1 && elem.value) {
            elem.value += ',' + chosenId;
        } else {
            document.getElementById(name).value = chosenId;
        }
        win.close();
    }

    function showRelatedObjectPopup(triggeringLink) {
        return showAdminPopup(triggeringLink, /^(change|add|delete)_/, false);
    }

    function updateRelatedObjectLinks(triggeringLink) {
        var $this = $(triggeringLink);
        var siblings = $this.nextAll('.change-related, .delete-related');
        if (!siblings.length) {
            return;
        }
        var value = $this.val();
        if (value) {
            siblings.each(function() {
                var elm = $(this);
                elm.attr('href', elm.attr('data-href-template').replace('__fk__', value));
            });
        } else {
            siblings.removeAttr('href');
        }
    }

    function dismissAddRelatedObjectPopup(win, newId, newRepr) {
        var name = windowname_to_id(win.name);
        var elem = document.getElementById(name);
        if (elem) {
            var elemName = elem.nodeName.toUpperCase();
            if (elemName === 'SELECT') {
                elem.options[elem.options.length] = new Option(newRepr, newId, true, true);
            } else if (elemName === 'INPUT') {
                if (elem.className.indexOf('vManyToManyRawIdAdminField') !== -1 && elem.value) {
                    elem.value += ',' + newId;
                } else {
                    elem.value = newId;
                }
            }
            // Trigger a change event to update related links if required.
            $(elem).trigger('change');
        } else {
            var toId = name + "_to";
            var o = new Option(newRepr, newId);
            SelectBox.add_to_cache(toId, o);
            SelectBox.redisplay(toId);
        }
        win.close();
    }

    function dismissChangeRelatedObjectPopup(win, objId, newRepr, newId) {
        var id = windowname_to_id(win.name).replace(/^edit_/, '');
        var selectsSelector = interpolate('#%s, #%s_from, #%s_to', [id, id, id]);
        var selects = $(selectsSelector);
        selects.find('option').each(function() {
            if (this.value === objId) {
                this.textContent = newRepr;
                this.value = newId;
            }
        });
        win.close();
    }

    function dismissDeleteRelatedObjectPopup(win, objId) {
        var id = windowname_to_id(win.name).replace(/^delete_/, '');
        var selectsSelector = interpolate('#%s, #%s_from, #%s_to', [id, id, id]);
        var selects = $(selectsSelector);
        selects.find('option').each(function() {
            if (this.value === objId) {
                $(this).remove();
            }
        }).trigger('change');
        win.close();
    }

    // Global for testing purposes
    window.id_to_windowname = id_to_windowname;
    window.windowname_to_id = windowname_to_id;

    window.showRelatedObjectLookupPopup = showRelatedObjectLookupPopup;
    window.dismissRelatedLookupPopup = dismissRelatedLookupPopup;
    window.showRelatedObjectPopup = showRelatedObjectPopup;
    window.updateRelatedObjectLinks = updateRelatedObjectLinks;
    window.dismissAddRelatedObjectPopup = dismissAddRelatedObjectPopup;
    window.dismissChangeRelatedObjectPopup = dismissChangeRelatedObjectPopup;
    window.dismissDeleteRelatedObjectPopup = dismissDeleteRelatedObjectPopup;

    // Kept for backward compatibility
    window.showAddAnotherPopup = showRelatedObjectPopup;
    window.dismissAddAnotherPopup = dismissAddRelatedObjectPopup;

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("a[data-popup-opener]").click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            opener.dismissRelatedLookupPopup(window, $(this).data("popup-opener"));
        });
        $('body').on('click', '.related-widget-wrapper-link', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (this.href) {
                var event = $.Event('django:show-related', {href: this.href});
                $(this).trigger(event);
                if (!event.isDefaultPrevented()) {
                    showRelatedObjectPopup(this);
                }
            }
        });
        $('body').on('change', '.related-widget-wrapper select', function(e) {
            var event = $.Event('django:update-related');
            $(this).trigger(event);
            if (!event.isDefaultPrevented()) {
                updateRelatedObjectLinks(this);
            }
        });
        $('.related-widget-wrapper select').trigger('change');
        $('body').on('click', '.related-lookup', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var event = $.Event('django:lookup-related');
            $(this).trigger(event);
            if (!event.isDefaultPrevented()) {
                showRelatedObjectLookupPopup(this);
            }
        });
    });

})(django.jQuery);
```

Comment: I don't see any Jquery in your current HTML, you need to import it for every HTML page you want to use it in.

Comment: Browser is making a fetch to https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js *before* any other .js downloads/execution in the current page? 200, no warnings?

Comment: @user2864740 no warnings at all.

Comment: ..and the Network tab shows a 200-OK for the jquery resource *before* any other scripts? (eg. browser not caching stale HTML page, include on HTML page as expected?)

Comment: Why do you have a script whose `src` points to a folder instead of a `.js` file?

Comment: You're not getting an error from bootstrap, but you are getting it from `RelatedObjectLookups.js`? That suggests that something in between them undefined `jQuery` and `$`.

Comment: Try putting breakpoints at the beginning of each script and see when it becomes undefined.

Comment: @Barmar copied from here  https://stackoverflow.com/a/12916263/3297613

Comment: at the end of `RelatedObjectLookups.js` script they have included `)(django.jQuery);`

Comment: likely the top of `RelatedObjectLookups.js` then looks like `(function($) {` and is expecting the jquery object to be passed in. If you aren't creating a `django` object and attaching jQuery to it anywhere that could be your problem. I don't know enough about dgango to know what that even means, but likely the jquery version from google's CDN isn't doing it. - Can you change that file? If so I'd try `window.jQuery` instead.

Comment: replacing `$(document.ready`  line no 177 with `django.jQuery( document ).ready(function($) ` works

Answer (score 1):

I’m pretty sure your whole problem is that the very end of your `RelatedObjectsLookups.js` JS file says `django.jQuery`, which doesn’t exist (or at least, the googleapis jQuery file you’re loading in isn’t going to define that). Change it to `window.jQuery` and things should work for you.

**EDIT based on your reply**

Since you can’t change the line that says `django.jQuery`, then let’s define that.

Right after you include your jQuery file, add the following tag.

```
<script>
  django = django || {};
  django.jQuery = django.jQuery || jQuery;
</script>
```

This will set django.jQuery to jQuery (which is included by your googleapis file), if it’s not been set yet. Now it will exist for your later scripts to use.

Comment: I can't change a library file