# Setting the Format for the Django DatetimeInput Widget

Tags: django, datetimepicker, datetime-format

I would like to use the included Django DateTimeInput widget as a datetimepicker on my website. No matter what I try however, the widget returns a datetime value in an incorrect format which will not send to my database.

I need the format `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`, but the widget returns `'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'`

This problem has been discussed a tad here:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/35968816/1382297

I believe the problem may be from setting the input_type to DateTime-local, but I don't know other options and cannot find any in the documentation. I've tried passing `format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'` to the widget, as well as `FORMAT_INPUTS = ['%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S']`, and tried initializing these in the DateInput class, all with no luck.

Here is my forms.py

```
class DateTimeInput(forms.DateTimeInput):
    input_type = 'datetime-local'


class EnterMatchForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = match
        fields = ('match_name', 'player1', 'player2', 'victory', 'match_description', 'match_date')
        widgets = {
               'match_date': DateTimeInput(),

        }
```

What is the right way to set up the widget so that it returns datetime values in the format Y-m-d H:M:S? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass `input_formats` not **formats** or **FORMAT_INPUTS**.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#datetimefield

Comment: Hmm, so I've added input_formats=['%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'] to the DateTimeInput class, and tried to pass it in the widgets line, when I add it to the class, the format is still wrong, and if I pass it as DateTimeInput(input_formats=['%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S']) i get the error TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'input_formats'. Am i just setting it up wrong?