# DateTime picker in pure Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I need to have a picker for DateTimeField, but I dont really know how to do it. Ive tried admin widget but I think I did it wrong. The closest thing to a solution was:

**models.py**

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    myfield = models.DateTimeField()
```

**forms.py**

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        widgets = {'myfield': forms.widgets.SplitDateTimeWidget(
            date_attrs={'type': 'date'}. time_attrs={'type': 'time'})}
```

It shows me a working picker, but when I try to press save button it says me an error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
> response = get_response(request)
> File "C:pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
> response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
> File "C:pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
> response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
> File "C:pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
> return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
> File "C:pythonProject\MyProject\MyApp\views.py", line 40, in new_table_field
> if form.is_valid():
> File "C:pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 185, in is_valid
> return self.is_bound and not self.errors
> File "C:pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 180, in errors
> self.full_clean()
> File "C:pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 381, in full_clean
> self._clean_fields()
> File "C:pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 399, in _clean_fields
> value = field.clean(value)
> File "C:pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\fields.py", line 148, in clean
> value = self.to_python(value)
> File "C:pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\fields.py", line 462, in to_python
> result = super().to_python(value)
> File "C:pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\fields.py", line 379, in to_python
> value = value.strip()
> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'

Comment: Show us the full error traceback!

Comment: @KlausD. added a full traceback

Comment: If you don't want to install other modules check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35968816/7373966

Comment: @FlorinC. i saw it but it's for DateField and I need for DateTimeField, maybe u know how to do it for me?

Comment: Yeah, sure, here it is: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/widgets/#datetimeinput