# DateField in Django Forms shows like simple text input

Tags: django, datetime, django-forms, datefield

My Form:

```
date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
```

My HTML:

```html
<div class="col-md-3">
    <label class="form-label">Date</label>
        {{ form.date }}
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                Enter Date
            </div>
    </label>
</div>
```

Also, I don't want to add the type "date" in my forms.

Issue picture:
[image]

Comment: This answer could help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3367091/whats-the-cleanest-simplest-to-get-running-datepicker-in-django

Comment: Are you using this package? https://pypi.org/project/django-jalali/

Comment: Yes I am. 
but I guess the problem is with my front-end part. because I used the same thing in models and it works fine in admin templates.
also I checked normal datefileds that django has but the problem was the same.

Answer (score 2):

The way how I handle it is the following:

```
date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'type':'date'}))
```

Other ways more elegant is to use a javascript widget like `DatetimeUI` but it is the easiest way I think.

Comment: thanks for your time. but I'm trying to use Jalali Calendar and type "date" is not working on as I want to.

Comment: @EnigmaBeyond Make the clarification in your question. In that way probably others will can help you.