# Can users switch months on website using python calendar library

Tags: python, html, django, calendar

I am making web application with django. I am using python calendar library to create HTML calendar. I was wondering if there is a builtin way to allow users switch months while on website or if I have to make it work using JavaScript.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the cleanest, simplest-to-get running datepicker in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3367091/whats-the-cleanest-simplest-to-get-running-datepicker-in-django)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not strictly related  to back end side and and python. If you use jQuery for you front end part of website and  There are some plugins like [datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/). But it depends that what technology you want to use in frond end of you app. Static html is not enough. for example in react you can use [calender](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-calendar) library and so on.