# How to set calender form in list_filter for datetime field in django admin?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-admin-filters

models.py:

```
class XYZ(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    start = models.DateTimeField()
    end = models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

admin.py:

```
class XYZAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = (start,)

admin.site.register(XYZ,XYZAdmin)
```

and it's return

[image]

now I want to change this filter to a pop-up calender and select custom start datateime and filter them.

like this image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need a date picker; check out [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3367091/whats-the-cleanest-simplest-to-get-running-datepicker-in-django) for some possible alternatives.